# How to add background image in bar chart column in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

In chart.js, I added a background image (img.src, from a url) to a barchart but the background is working only with `repeat`, not `repeat-y`.

```js
var img = new Image();
img.src = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/graphpattern.png';
img.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var fillPattern=ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
    //repeat-y not working==>ctx.createPattern(img,'repeat-y');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4'],
            datasets: [{
                data: [5,20, 35, 45],
                backgroundColor: fillPattern
            }]
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: give us a working example to run !

Comment: Here is the link @MajidNayyeri

http://codepen.io/shan31/pen/OpYRmN

Answer (score 0):

`ctx.createPattern()` [is a 2d canvas function](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_createpattern.asp), with [patchy standards](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/12/Canvas-driven-background-images?hl=en). I found the behavior for `repeat-x` and `repeat-y` to vary between browsers. The example linked here works in Firefox (apart from the series icon missing the background image with repeat-y) and is blank in Chromium, but the situation reverses for this [W3Schools example](http://w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_createpattern), Chromium working and Firefox only working with `repeat` and `no-repeat`, likely  due to a [long-standing bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=468358).

The provided code is barely modified from a [Chart.js sample](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html) and looks fine other than an "[Unable to parse color from object](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4279)" error, that may or may not have been related; the problem is likely a mix of library and browser rather than anything in the code. For anyone else trying for a simple patterned background, I recommend cutting losses and using the pattern method mentioned in the last two links.